# Django-haystack document=True field

Tags: django, full-text-search, django-haystack

As far as I understood from reading about full-text search engines, Document is actually the entire entity we are looking for, not just a single field within it...
So this "document=True field" approach seems somewhat confusing

As the docs says

> This indicates to both Haystack and the search engine about which field is the primary field for searching within.

Ok but here is my (and quite common I suppose) use-case:
There are 2 fields within the model - title and some description.
Title is definately the primary one and I'd like matches on that field to be of higher weight than the others.

There is such a mechanism as Field Boost that should help in achieving that goal but the example provided with documentation on that matter is even more confusing:

```
class NoteSearchIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable): 
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True) 
    title = indexes.CharField(model_attr='title', boost=1.125)
```

So we see that 'title' field is boosted but it doesn't have a 'document=True' on it. But it is the primary field. The previous quote said the primary field should have 'document=True'...

And also, what should I place into that 'document=True' field? Should it be some concatenation of all relevant fields on the model or maybe all but the 'title' field since I've already declared it separately?

Would appreciate a more precise explanation of what 'document=True' field actually is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Haystack builds its index of text, by examining a “document” of text for each model instance. Commonly, you need that document to be aggregated from multiple model fields; if so, you can use a template.

> Every SearchIndex requires there be one (and only one) field with `document=True`. This indicates to both Haystack and the search engine about which field is the primary field for searching within.

Note that it's not referring to a model field there! It is the *SearchIndex* which has the field with `document=True`. Conventionally, that field is named `text`.

The SearchIndex does not point simply to the Model, as you're aware. You define a Schema that describes what fields will be indexed. This is different from what fields are on the Model!

If you have this model:

```py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Note(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField()
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    body = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

You might design this SearchIndex, which specifies the schema of fields to index:

```py
import datetime
from haystack import indexes
from myapp.models import Note


class NoteIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    author = indexes.CharField(model_attr='user')
    pub_date = indexes.DateTimeField(model_attr='pub_date')

    def get_model(self):
        return Note

    def index_queryset(self, using=None):
        """Used when the entire index for model is updated."""
        return self.get_model().objects.filter(pub_date__lte=datetime.datetime.now())
```

> what should I place into that 'document=True' field? Should it be some concatenation of all relevant fields on the model or maybe all but the 'title' field since I've already declared it separately?

Yes.

That `use_template=True` argument tells Haystack that the field content should be rendered using a template specifically for that SearchIndex field. The template name Haystack looks for is `search/indexes/{app_label}/{model_name}_{field_name}.txt`.

In this case, where the field is `NoteIndex.text`, and the corresponding model is `myapp.Note`, Haystack looks for the template `search/indexes/myapp/note_text.txt`. Define that template so that it gathers all the relevant text into one document for the model instance:

```
{{ object.title }}
{{ object.user.get_full_name }}
{{ object.body }}
```

All of these examples come from the [Haystack getting started tutorial](https://django-haystack.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html).